# How to create admin form using UI component in 2-column layout with tab in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.2, magento2.3

I have created a form using UI component and added tab in the form. I used the reference from 
`/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`. I can see the tabs in left but form is not loaded and only loading spinner is showing. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Admin form using tabs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168191/admin-form-using-tabs)

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked not this link but one argument that I was providing was  wrong argument. I was providing collapsible template path in the argument on top.